# There are no arguments that depend on a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to do the following:

```
template <class T>
std::ifstream& operator>> (std::ifstream& fin, List<T> l)
{
    T temp;
    l.resize(0);
    fin >> ignore(1,'\t');
    for(ListIterator<T> i=l.begin();i!=l.end();i++)
    {
        fin >> ignore(1,'\t') >> temp;
        l.push_back(temp);
    }
    return fin;
}
```

I have to read all the contents from a file. Each field is separated by `'\t'` character, so I have to ignore the `'\t'` characters.

The error log is the following:

```
/home/ramy/Documents/C++/Prova/Util.h||In function ‘std::ifstream& Util::operator>> (std::ifstream&, Util::List<T>)’:|
/home/ramy/Documents/C++/Prova/Util.h|431|error: there are no arguments to ‘ignore’ that  depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘ignore’ must be available|
/home/ramy/Documents/C++/Prova/Util.h|431|note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will  accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: It is better to copy+paste the error message for searching purposes, i.e. there is a typo in your title: `tamplate`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

For builtin types, [argument dependent lookup (ADL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_dependent_lookup) is not performed, therefore, an `ignore` symbol must be "imported" into the current namespace.

You can, for example, do this; from most preferred to least preferred (i.e. to most intrusive and name polluting):

- `foobar::ignore (...)`
- `using foobar::ignore; ignore(...);`
- `using namespace foobar; ignore(...);`

The error message comes up like this because in templates, you also enter the realm of dependent names and [Two Phase Lookup](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/087.htm). Names that depend on a template parameter, e.g.

```
template <typename T> void foo() {
    T x;
    x.frobnicate();
}
```

are looked up in phase 2, which is upon instantiation. Names that do not depend on template parameters, like

```
class Foo {};

template <typename T> void foo() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.frobnicate();
}
```

must be resolvable in the first phase.

This separation helps template authors to find bugs earlier and to find correct symbols, and it helps making templates more generic. For example, in C# generics, everything must be resolvable, which puts rather stringent limits on their flexibility (because everything that *may* be used by a generic *must* be defined). Oppositely, some old C++ compilers resolved in phase 2 only, i.e. at instantiation time, which had some subtle consequences for lookup and error finding.

The C++ 2-phase model combines the best of the eager-model (C#) and the lazy-model (some old C++ compilers).

Answer (score 65):

For an easier answer, see
https://web.archive.org/web/20130423054841/http://www.agapow.net/programming/cpp/no-arguments-that-depend-on-a-template-parameter

TL;DR: replace ignore() with this->ignore() and your problem will go away.

Comment: the link is rotten now :(

Comment: @sidewinderguy - I've come across the exact same behavior.  I tried gazing at phresnel's answer above to glean some knowledge about it, but the "why" still eludes me.  Too bad the link is dead.  :(

Comment: Am I the only one shocked by the sentence "This is why C++ should just die and give way to Java." ?

Comment: For which `this`? The code and error message in the question do not feature member functions.

Comment: @Syndog: The `this` solution does not help in the OP's situation actually, so John's answer is incorrect. However, in case of template class member functions (i.e. a member function of a templated class (like Foo<T>::ignore()), `this->ignore` forces the compiler to interpret `ignore` as a _dependent name_ which is fully looked up only in phase 2. The motivation behind this is explained in my answer :)

Comment: @BenoitBlanchon: No, you're not. While I recognize the ugliness of C++' syntax, one cannot expect to make use of a very complex language feature ("hey let's just write a templated function and be a cool kid") without knowing about very basic error messages and mechanisms. Nothing wrong with not knowing (we all once knew nothing, right?), but recommending to murder C++ for such basic non-knowledge of an advanced feature is incompetent at best. "Hey, what are those long names and dependency inversion orgasms? This is why Java should ...."

Answer (score 16):

The error message means that there is no definition of `ignore` that the compiler can use at this point. It is exactly the same error that you get if you do:

```
void f() {
   g();
}
void g() {}
```

... even if it looks *very* different. Note that there is no ADL issue here as the other answers say. The reason that the error message is so convoluted is because of the way that templates are processed by the compiler.

Templates are processed in two passes, during the first pass everything that is not dependent on the instantiating type must be verified *without performing the type substitution*, during this pass every non-dependent name must be checked, and in this case the compiler has failed to resolve `ignore` with the declarations available at the place of definition of the template.

If the expression depended on the type arguments to the template, it would not need to be fully resolved during the first pass and it would be tried again *after* type substitution, with the declarations available at the place of instantiation.

Comment: this did it for me, 9 years later haha

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem and I've fixed it by changing include order.

As phresnel says, the compiler cannot resolve that on the 1st phase, which in my case was because the header with the problematic template method was included before the one with the inner method that couldn't be resolved.

Adding the needed header include removed the error for me. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the weather your problem is solved or not and I hope it would have.

Whenever I face the problem of **"There are no arguments that depend on a template parameter"** I override the method and call the parent class member function.

To show what I mean consider a class below which is template class ADT

```
template <typename DataTypeOfNode>
class LinearList
{
public:
    LinearList(){}
    void addAtBeg(DataTypeOfNode data) {
        //Inside implementation....
    }
    DataTypeOfNode removeFromFront() {
        //Inside implementation....
    } 

    // And many more useful methods
    ~LinearList(){}

};
```

Now if you inherit this class with a base class say **"PriorityQueue"** like this

```
template <typename DataTypeOfNode>
class PriorityQueue : public LinearList<DataTypeOfNode>
{
public:

    void enqueue(DataTypeOfNode data){
        addAtBeg(data);
    }

    DataTypeOfNode dequeue(){
        return removeFromFront() ; 
    }
    PriorityQueue(){}
    ~PriorityQueue(){}
};
```

After compliling you will get error like **"There are no arguments that depend on a template parameter"** for `removeFromFront()` and `addAtBeg()` methods becaouse they have template parameters.

To fix this error you just need to override these methods and call the parent class methods like this

```
template <typename DataTypeOfNode>
class PriorityQueue : public LinearList<DataTypeOfNode>
{
public:

    //Calling parent class methods

    void addAtBeg(DataTypeOfNode data){
        LinearList<DataTypeOfNode>::addAtBeg(data) ; 
    }

    DataTypeOfNode removeFromFront(){
        return LinearList<DataTypeOfNode>::removeFromFront() ; 
    }

    void enqueue(DataTypeOfNode data){
        addAtBeg(data);
    }

    DataTypeOfNode dequeue(){
        return removeFromFront() ; 
    }
    PriorityQueue(){}
    ~PriorityQueue(){}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that `ignore` cannot be found by the compiler and ADL cannot kick in. This means that there is no suitably-scoped `ignore` function.