# infix to postfix using overloaded istream operator

Tags: templates, operator-overloading, postfix-notation, infix-notation

My teacher has given my class a program that converts an infix expression like A+B*C into postfix. I have finished the other pieces of code but the overloaded istream operator is giving me some problem. This is the error I'm getting:

error: there are no arguments to 'convertToPostfix' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'convertToPostfix' must be available [-fpermissive]|

Here's the code for the istream operator:

```
template <class U>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, expression<U>& e) {
    char c;
    e.ifix ="";
    e.pfix ="";
    do {
        in >> e;
        e.pfix += c;
    }while(c!='.' || c!=';');

    convertToPostfix();

    return in;
}
```

My teacher told us to put convertToPostfix before the return statement so it returns both the infix and postfix expression at the same time. I'm looking for code correctness as feedback. Thank you in advance for any help you give me.

Answer (score 0):

The main error looks like this one:

[There are no arguments that depend on a template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9941987/14065)

But in addition you have forgotten to assign to `c`;

```
// Declared
char c;

// Used here
e.pfix += c;               // What is the value of `c` here?

// and here
while(c!='.' || c!=';');   // What is the value of `c` here?
                           // If you don't explicitly assign it a value
                           // contains a random value.
```

I suspect you want to read the next no space character from the input into `c`.

Also this line:

```
in >> e;
```

Seems to be a recursive definition. Which definately does not look correct.

Comment: what do you mean by assign to c?

Comment: At the moment the variable `c` has an undefined value (ie it contains random garbage). Unless you assign some value it is illegal to use it in any way.