# Compile-time pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, templates

I've tried implementing a list container,
and decided to move some general functions
like `sum()` to base class, so that I can
reuse them later in other containers.

All the base support class needs are three
methods `empty()`, `head()` and `tail`.
I can't make those pure virtual because support
class will never be instantiated. But it still
has to use those methods to implement its own
methods like `sum()`.

I tried something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class StatsSupport {
public:
    T sum(void) const {
        if (empty()) {
            return T(0);
        } else {
            return head() + tail()->sum;
        }
    }

    // other methods
};

template<typename T>
class List : public StatsSupport<T> {
public:
    // constructors etc.

    bool empty(void) const {return head_ != NULL;}
    const T& head(void) const {return *head_;}
    const List<T>& tail(void) const {return *tail_;}

    // other methods
private:
    T* head_;
    List<T> *tail_;
};
```

But trying to use `sum()` gets me compilation error

```
prog.cpp:8:13: error: there are no arguments to 'empty' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'empty' must be available [-fpermissive]
   if (empty()) {
             ^
```

for each of `empty()`, `head()` and `tail()`.

Any advice?

Comment: I don't think it is clever to derive the containers from classes which add extra functionality. It is kind of reverse OOP. Having said that, I also think it would be a bad idea to derive your expansions from the containers. As this would lead to old school OOP of the fragile kind. Instead, the "my modern way" (Tm) would be to write your expansions as templates which take the container with the container contract as a template argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [There are no arguments that depend on a template parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941987/there-are-no-arguments-that-depend-on-a-template-parameter)

Comment: This *almost* looks like you're trying to implement a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but forgot what is the *container* and what is the *contained*. Either that or 3:00am is way too late for me to be looking at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `StatsSupport` cannot find the `empty`, `head` etc. functions because these neither exist in its nor in the global scope.
`StatsSupport` does not know about the functions that exist in the derived class.

Basically there are two ways to solve this:

- Runtime polymorphism, where you add a virtual destructor to `StatsSupport` and add declarations for `empty`, `head` etc. which are pure virtual.
- Compile time polymorphism via using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) as mentioned in the comments.
  I will focus on the latter.

So basically `StatsSupport` needs to get a way to access functions of the derived class.
This can be done by adding the type of the derived class as template parameter, which is called [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template<class Derived, typename T>
class StatsSupport {
public:
    T sum(void) const {
        if (derived()->empty()) {
            return T(0);
        } else {
            return derived()->head() + derived()->tail()->sum;
        }
    }

    // other methods
    private:
        Derived *derived()
        {
            return static_cast<Derived*>(this);
        }
        const Derived *derived() const
        {
            return static_cast<const Derived*>(this);
        }
};

template<typename T>
class List : public StatsSupport<List<T>, T> { // with some changes could be simplified to StatsSupport<List<T>> but this it ouf of scope of this question
```

I am using a function for `derived` instead of a member to keep the class const correct.

Of course another alternative would be a different design relying on algorithms. There you move `sum` and all the other functions of `StatsSupport` into global namesapce and would then access them like `sum(my_container_instance)`.
A more STL like way would be to use iterators. Then you could use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) to do the summing.

Answer (score 0):

That's a serious design issue:  Your `StatSupport` defines some general functions, but relies on specifics of its child classes.

So when StatSupport gets compiled, it doesn't even know that there is some `head()` and `tail()`. That's why you get the error message

Now imagine that one day you want to define other containers that shall inherit from `StatSupport`, for example your own Vector or Map, or DataBase.  These data structures will not have a head and a tail.

Basically there are two main orientations you may take:

- define in your StatSupport some virtual functions for iterating through the data structure.
- or better, use in your data structures some iterators (like they exist for standard containers) and define some template functions (sum, average, etc...) that use iterators to browse through your container.

In the latter case, you wouldn't need inheritance to benefit from generic functions.

Comment: `StatSupport` is a policy class, so it's made with those methods intentionally to not compile if derived classes do not define them, just like dynamically polymorphic class relies on its derived classes to implement pure virtual functions, or it won't compile otherwise.

Comment: Ok ! Would have been useful to clarify this in the question already.

Answer (score 0):

I might miss the point of the question but will give my 5 cents to it anyway :)

The reasoning behind the solution I show below is, that often people new to OOP (in C++) think that they must use inheritance to get things done.

But especially in C++, this is but one way and often not the best way to achieve composition.

While in the majority of cases, the overhead cost of virtual functions does not really matter, the code below shows a way to yield container expansions without using inheritance and without using virtual functions. The weak point of the approach is that the "container function contract" is only implicitly visible.

```
template <class _X>
class ContainerTypeA < _X >
{
public:
    typedef _X value_type;
    typedef ContainerTypeA<_X> container_type;

    const _X & Head() const
    {
        // return head of this containers content.
    }
    container_type Tail() const
    {
        // return the tail (all elements after the first element in a new instance.
    }
    bool IsEmpty() const
    {
        return true; // return whether or not this container is empty.
    }
};

template <class _X>
class ContainerTypeB < _X >
{
public:
    typedef _X value_type;
    typedef ContainerTypeB<_X> container_type;

    const _X & Head() const
    {
        // return head of this containers content.
    }
    container_type Tail() const
    {
        // return the tail (all elements after the first element) in a new instance.
    }
    bool IsEmpty() const
    {
        return true; // return whether or not this container is empty.
    }
};

// Note: In stead of the class with static member functions, this could 
// as well be a namespace with template-functions inside.
template < class _ContainerT >
class ContainerStats<_ContainerT>
{
    static _ContainerT::value_type Sum(const _ContainerT & container)
    {
        // Implement sum - possibly in the recursive way you did in your question.
    }
    // more expansion functions...
};
```