# Define and use private methods not in header file

Tags: c++

I have a situation where I am not allowed to modify the header file for my class. I want to add just a helper function to use with one of my functions.. but cant quite figure out the correct way to implement it. Normally I try google but couldn't find any help on there.

Here is my current code:

```
    template<typename T>
void Set<T>::doubleRotateRight(Elem *& node) {
    // you fill in here
    rotateRight(node->left);
    rotateLeft(node);

    //call private helper not defined in header
    privmed();

}
void privmed(){
    //out << "who" << endl;
}
```

However, when I run this I get the error:

```
error: there are no arguments to ‘privmed’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘privmed’ must be available [-fpermissive]
     privmed();
```

Any help with this would be incredible!

Comment: In C++ everything must be declared before it is used. Have you tried moving the `privmed` function implementation to before the `doubleRotateRight` function?

Comment: Voted to close as **unclear**. Needs info about what can be modified and what cannot be modified; needs info about what `privmed` is meant to be doing; needs info about the goal(s).

Comment: cmon.... thanks a lot

Comment: *"I am not allowed to modify the header file".* The code you are showing is in that header, is it not?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe that code is in the .cpp file.. I could be wrong but pretty sure that isn't that header

Comment: @JoeCaraccio  You can't have `template<typename T>
void Set<T>::doubleRotateRight(Elem *& node)` in the cpp file.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Question is unanswerable under the conditions posted. It is based on flawed premises.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe you are completely wrong.. You can.. I do right now.. and without the private function it runs fine.. please.. if you don't want to help me that is fine.. but don't come and say wrong withings

Comment: Did you try to find any info about this error e.g. here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941987/there-are-no-arguments-that-depend-on-a-template-parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a lambda:

```
template<typename T>
void Set<T>::doubleRotateRight(Elem *& node)
{
    static auto const privmed = []() -> void 
    {
        //out << "who" << endl;
    };

    // you fill in here
    rotateRight(node->left);
    rotateLeft(node);

    //call private helper not defined in header
    privmed();
}
```

Comment: Well, then declare a local class and use a `static` member function in that class.

Comment: Or, depending on what you mean, you might make do with the lambda calling the `doubleRotateRight` function or some other function that in turn calls it. It's hard to sketch solutions without a very concrete question. But anything recursive is doable: how to do it just depends on what it is.

Comment: when i run the code you posted it just says "‘privmed’ does not name a type"

Comment: well my goal was to be able to run that helper function and have it call itself reccursively

Comment: I don't  think that's the code I posted you got that error from. You need to be way more clear about things (e.g., what's your header file, what's your goal, exactly how recursive) in order to get good answers other than by chance.'

Comment: What the heck man? its clear enough... I need to figure out how to call the method without defining it in the header file.. thats my question.. if you could unclose my question that would be great.. instead of making things more difficult for me..

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you have to define the "privmed()" function before you use it, like this:

```
void privmed(){
    //out << "who" << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void Set<T>::doubleRotateRight(Elem *& node) {
    // you fill in here
    rotateRight(node->left);
    rotateLeft(node);

    //call private helper not defined in header
    privmed();
}
```

Comment: As I understand it this messes with the header file, which the OP is constrained from doing.