# How can I resolve calloc() error in .cpp and .hpp files?

Tags: c++, templates, unix, g++, calloc

I try to run a `.cpp` with a `.hpp` file in Linux using this command: `g++ -c main.cpp` but I have this error about `calloc()`:

```
error: there are no arguments to ‘calloc’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘calloc’ must be available [-fpermissive]
   Tr=(T *)calloc(Rows*Colomns, sizeof(T));

In member function ‘T* MyMatrix::Adjoint()’:
MyMatrix.hpp:276:35: error: there are no arguments to ‘calloc’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘calloc’ must be available [-fpermissive]
   Temp = (T*)calloc(N*N, sizeof(T));
```

I noticed that this code works in Microsoft Visual Studio:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

template <typename T>
class MyMatrix {
private:
    int Rows;
    int Colomns;
    T* A; //Matricea
    T* Tr; //Transpusa acesteia
    float* Inv; //Inversa
public:
    MyMatrix(int L, int C)
    {

        Rows = L;
        Colomns = C;

        A = (T*)calloc(Rows * Colomns, sizeof(T));
        if (A == NULL)
            throw("Eroare la alocarea matricii! :(");
    }

    MyMatrix(T* S, int L, int C)
        : MyMatrix(L, C)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Rows * Colomns; ++i)
            A[i] = S[i];
    }

    ~MyMatrix() { free(A); }

    void Transposed()
    {
        Tr = (T*)calloc(Rows * Colomns, sizeof(T));
        for (int i = 0; i < Colomns; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < Rows; ++j)
                Tr[j * Colomns + i] = A[i * Rows + j];
    }

    void Inverse()
    { //some code
        T* Adj = Adjoint();
        Inv = (float*)calloc(Rows * Rows, sizeof(float));
        for (int i = 0; i < this->Rows * this->Rows; ++i)
            Inv[i] = Adj[i] / (float)Det;
    }
};

#endif // MYMATRIX_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Best fix would be to not use `calloc` at all.  Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There are no arguments that depend on a template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941987/there-are-no-arguments-that-depend-on-a-template-parameter)

Comment: If you have a desparate urge for manual memory management, you should use `new[]` and `delete[]`, not the C functions.

Comment: Look up which header `calloc` is declared in.

Comment: Stop writing C in C++! Just use `std::vector` and apply "rule of zero".

Answer (score 4):

> a declaration of ‘calloc’ must be available

The solution is to declare `calloc` before using it. Since it is a standard function, it must be declared by including the standard header that is specified to declare it.

`calloc` is declared in the header `<stdlib.h>`. Note that the `.h` suffixed headers from the C standard library are deprecated in favour of using the `c` prefixed headers such as `<cstdlib>`. However, the `c` prefixed headers declare the functions in the `std` namespace which you have failed to use in this case.

So the complete solution is to include `<cstdlib>`, and use `std::calloc`.

---

However, you don't need to use `calloc` at all. Better solution is to use `std::make_unique` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score -1):

As the error message suggests, the g++ compiler used here does not have an implementation wherein the second parameter is a template type   i.e. the compiler recognizes the arguments when the second argument is of type int or float because these are the types the compiler knows about its 'calloc' implementation works with these types BUT it does not recognize when the second argument is of a templated type.
Visual Studio used here probably has an implementation which allows template types to be passed to 'calloc'.
Maybe you can try updating the g++ compiler to the latest and then it might support what you are trying to do here.

hope this helps!

Comment: No, `T` is not "a template type" and the problem has nothing to do with the types passed to `calloc`. The problem is simply that the appropriate header declaring `calloc` has not been included.